# How can i get Bearer token using basic authentication using python?

Tags: python, locust

I want to get an authorization token using basic authorization. I send a post request using my user name and password but to get the token a body data which is raw text `grant_type=client_credentials&scope=Dashboard` must contain in the request. but I cannot send the `grant_type=client_credentials&scope=Dashboard` body data in the post request using python.

```
    @task(1)
    def login(self):
        self.client.post("/OAuth/Token/", {'Username':'abc', 'Password':'12345'})
```

Comment: what is `self.client.post` in this context? Are you using some kind of OAuth provider? Ifso, which? Also, `grant_type=client_credentials&scope=Dashboard` looks more like parameters instead of body

Comment: self.client.post is just a post request "grant_type=client_credentials&scope=Dashboard" is a body data which is in text format

Comment: @alec_a I used "grant_type=client_credentials&scope=Dashboard" as a body data (text) in postman

Comment: The user name and password used for basic authorization

Answer (score 1):

`self.client.post()` returns a Response object. You can see the api at https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/#requests.Response

To read out something in the response you can try something like

```
@task(1)
def login(self):
    res = self.client.post("/OAuth/Token/", {'Username':'abc', 'Password':'12345'})
    token = res.json()['token']
```

This attempts to process the Response body as json and pull out the token field. If this doesn't work please provide details on what you are seeing in the response.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

In the URL, Append the Grant type and Scope as shown below:

`/OAuth/Token?grant_type=client_credentials&scope=Dashboard`

It will look like this

`self.client.post("/OAuth/Token?grant_type=client_credentials&scope=Dashboard", {'Username':'abc', 'Password':'12345'})`